# (raspberry pi csi camera) Reading h264 data from raspivid-stdout with java

Tags: java, inputstream, stdout, h.264, raspberry-pi

I want to write an java application which reads the h264 stream from the raspberry pi csi camera.
The interface for the csi camera is the commando line c program "raspivid" which normally writes the captured video into a file.
With the option "-o -" raspivid writes the video to stdout, at this point I want to capture the h264 stream and "pipe" it without changing the data.
My first step was to write an application which reads the data from stdout and writes it into a file without changing the data (so you get a playable .h264 file).
My problem is that the written file is always corrupt, when I open the corrupt file with notepad++ I can see that there are general different "symbols" compared with a playable one.
I think the problem is the InputStreamReader() class, which converts the stdout-byte-stream to a character-stream.
I am not able to find the right class for this.
This is my actual code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {
    System.out.println("START PROGRAM");
    try
    {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("raspivid -w 100 -h 100 -n -t 5000 -o -");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("testvid.h264");
    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
    BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    while (bri.read() != -1)
    {
      out.write(bri.read());
    }

    bri.close();
    out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("END PROGRAM");
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the problem!
The InputStreamReader was not necessary and converted the byte-stream to a character-stream, a back conversion was not possible!
This is the working code (writes stdout-byte-stream to a file):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    System.out.println("START PROGRAM");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try
    {

      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("raspivid -w 100 -h 100 -n -t 10000 -o -");
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream());
      //Direct methode p.getInputStream().read() also possible, but BufferedInputStream gives 0,5-1s better performance
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("testvid.h264");

      System.out.println("start writing");
      int read = bis.read();
      fos.write(read);

      while (read != -1)
      {
        read = bis.read();
        fos.write(read);
      }
      System.out.println("end writing");
      bis.close();
      fos.close();

    }
    catch (IOException ieo)
    {
      ieo.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("END PROGRAM");
    System.out.println("Duration in ms: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=43756) from the Raspi forums might have some useful info.

In terms of the correct class, OutputStreamWriter looks like it's [doing a conversion you don't need to happen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html). Your stream's in bytes. It needs to stay that way.

Do you need a [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)?

EDIT: WHOOPS! Misread. You already have a fos. But for sure your writer is doing a conversion.